# Unable to integrate auditing using paper_trail gem in rails 2 application from plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Steps which I  followed

1. Installed a Gem paper_trail 1.4.0
2. ruby script/generate paper_trail
3. rake db:migrate
4. Add has_paper_trail to the models you want to track of models which I created in my plugin.

```
class AlphenaPaygrade < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_paper_trail
    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

I am getting the error below:

```
/home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1959:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `has_paper_trail' for #<Class:0x7f3beaa90f60> (NameError)
from /home/rank/rails/rank_fedena/app/models/user.rb:20
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `load_file'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:379:in `load_file'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `require_or_load'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:425:in `load_missing_constant'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
from /home/rank/rails/rank_fedena/vendor/plugins/fedena_bigbluebutton/lib/fedena_bigbluebutton.rb:22
from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /home/rank/rails/rank_fedena/vendor/plugins/fedena_bigbluebutton/init.rb:17:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /home/rank/rails/rank_fedena/config/environment.rb:20
from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from script/server:3
```

Can anybody please help me to integrate this?
I have been unable to integrate for the last 2 days, please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your vendor/plugins/plugin/config/custom_environment.rb

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

config.gem 'paper_trail',:version => '~> 1.4.0'

end

write the rake task in your rake file..

namespace :plugin name do
 desc "Install your Module"
 task :install do

```
if File.exists?("#{Rails.root}/config/environment.rb")
 src = File.read("#{Rails.root}/vendor/plugins/plugin/config/custom_environment.rb")
 File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/environment.rb", "w") do |file|
   file.puts(src)
 end
```

end
 end
end

install your plugin then it will work fine.....